# How to set line-buffer in Windows?

Tags: c++, c, windows, file, caching

In Linux, we can use `void setlinebuf(FILE * stream);` or 
`int setvbuf(FILE *stream, char *buf, int mode, size_t size);` 
to set line-buffering for a `FILE`.

---

But Windows doesn't support either `setlinebuf` or `setvbuf::_IOLBF`.

`_IOLBF — For some systems, this provides line buffering. However, for Win32, the behavior is the same as _IOFBF - Full Buffering.`

---

So how to set line-buffering (for `fprintf`)?

Comment: I like this questions: it seems to be an obvious omission from the Microsoft C runtime, and I guess all you can do it build in wrappers to your own code it you need to force line-buffering behavior.